# trying to POST to w3c validator with python script

Tags: python, post, curl

I'm trying to use [this](http://github.com/seisen/urllib2_file/blob/master/test-upload.py) python script to upload a file to the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload).

```
~/Desktop/urllib2_file$ python test-upload.py -u http://validator.w3.org/ -f ../index.php -n uploaded_file -p Content-Type=text/html > ../results.html && firefox ../results.html
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

cyraxjoe pointed out I needed to run it through php first. I tried this, but got the same result:

```
php -f /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php > index.html && python urllib2_file/test-upload.py -u http://validator.w3.org/ -f index.html -n uploaded_file -p Content-Type=text/html > results.html && firefox results.html
```

Comment: Why don't you validate directly with [pytidylib](http://countergram.com/software/pytidylib)? (Discussed in question: [Validate (X)HTML in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1279293/775066))

Answer (score 1):

You are uploading a php-script which is a server-side script, you need to upload the resulting html after the php procesing. Perhaps with php-cli then store in a file the resulting text and upload that file.

Comment: thats a great point, but i've tried this now, and still the same end result: php -f /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php > index.html && python urllib2_file/test-upload.py -u validator.w3.org -f index.html -n uploaded_file -p Content-Type=text/html > results.html && firefox results.html