# Parse html files in a directory and check if they are badly formed in Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, non-well-formed

I am hoping to write a script that will go through a directory and check if the html files are badly formed. Please see my code

```
directory = "html"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        if str(file).endswith('.html'):
              #Help needed here
              if file is badly formed:
                 print "Badly Formed"
              else:
                 print "Well Formed"
```

Comment: just to note I'm not looking to fix the html, I just want to know if it is badly formed

Comment: uhm....Your asking for us to write your code *for* you...Also, whats your definition of "Badly formed"?

Comment: Does 'Badly Formed" mean the file extension is not '.html'? Or does the script have to check the contents of the file?

Comment: Badly placed closing tags etc. I'm not asking for someoen to write the code but if I was pointed in the write direction

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538/validate-xhtml-in-python

Comment: Thank you Eric I will read this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ETree
....

    try:
        self.doc = ETree.parse( file )
        # do stuff with it ...
    except  ETree.ParseError :
        print( "ERROR in {0} : {1}".format( ETree.ParseError.filename, ETree.ParseError.msg ) )
```

Comment: Note that this only works if the HTML is also valid XML which is not necessarily the case. For a simple example, include any javascript scripts that have quotes or less than signs.